# server socket problems with more connections

Tags: c#, sockets, server

I try to send files via the socket, but when I try to find two files at the same time but two open sockets, the first socket dies.

I have looked at others who have coded the socket server but since they look different, I do not know what is wrong with my code, if there is someone here who might see the error and maybe can help, it would be very nice.

````
public static List<FileUppload> uploadlist = new List<FileUppload>();


        private static readonly Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        public static readonly List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 10485760; //2048 2097152
        private const int PORT = 100;
        private static readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
            CloseAllSockets();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File server");
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
            serverSocket.Listen(0);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            Console.WriteLine("File server har startat");
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket;

            try
            {
                socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Måste vara där för att ha kolla på alla anslutningar, så att man kan kicka dom som inte har loggat in!
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.Title = "Server Anslugningar: " + clientSockets.Count;
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected, waiting for request...");
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            ThreadStart ts = delegate
            {
                    #region encoding
                    Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received;

                try
                {
                    received = current.EndReceive(AR);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    //kick
                    Console.WriteLine("negerkuk");
                        clientKick(current);
                    return;
                }

                byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
                Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recBuf);

                try
                {
                    if (!Receive.GetData(text, current)) 
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine("negerfitta"); 
                        //clientKick(current); 
                        return; 
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        //kick
                        clientKick(current);
                    return;
                }
                    #endregion

                    current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
            };
            new Thread(ts).Start();
        }

        #region function
        private static void CloseAllSockets()
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }

            //Database.conn.Close();
            serverSocket.Close();
        }
        public static void clientSend(Socket socket, string text)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            socket.Send(data);
        }
        private static void clientKick(Socket socket)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
            // Don't shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway.
            socket.Close();
            clientSockets.Remove(socket);
            Console.Title = "Server Anslugningar: " + clientSockets.Count;
        }
        private static void clientSendAll(string text)
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
            {
                clientSend(socket, text);
            }
        }

        public static string read(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(path)) return string.Empty;

                using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(path))
                {
                    using (SHA1Managed checksum = new SHA1Managed())
                    {
                        return BitConverter.ToString(checksum.ComputeHash(file))
                            .Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }

            return string.Empty;
        }
        #endregion
    ```
````